# Can I set the preferred domain to get around differing content on www vs no-www?

Tags: seo, no-www

I am in the real estate industry and I am forced to serve content from servers at another host. I point to the content using a `www.` Subdomain referenced with a `CNAME`. Unfortunately, 15 years worth of links are pointing to pages on my non-www root domain that I host myself and I am not allowed to mirror my non-www pages on the servers hosting the www. Subdomain content.

i.e. `example.com/links.html` will not be found at `www.example.com/links.html`

If I tell Google that I prefer `www.example.com` will they expect to find the content mirrored there using the exact path?

I cannot replicate the exact path of my current non-www pages, but I can replicate them using a different path.

i.e. `example.com` can be replicated as `www.example.com/custom-pages/index/`
If I were to use a 301 to point `example.com` to `www.example.com/custom-pages/index/`

Would the new page still have all (or most of) the link power that domain.com/index.html had or would google not view a page in a subdirectory with as much favor as it shows my current root index page?

I am in a quandary because I effectively have two sites. All link power goes to the unimportant root domain and there are little to no external links to the `www.` Subdomain where all the content is. I’m looking for a solution as changing 15 years worth of links is impractical if not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure whether I have understood your problem correctly. Well, here's the crux of what I have been able to understand.

You have a domain - `example.com` which has canonical issues i.e. it can be accessed using both wwww and non-www versions. Now, both versions have different content and the link power is with the non-preferred version of the domain which has unimportant content.

Wow, that's complicated. How did you manage to do that?

What if I tell you to backup your unimportant content and move it to `old.example.com` and then using the `.htaccess` code redirect the non-preffered version of domain to the preferred one? TBH, I prefer to see the website first.website.

Comment: Therein lies the problem. I cannot move the files from domain.com to www.domain.com because www.domain.com is hosted on a different server and the admin will not allow me to store files on their server.

Comment: You need to find new hosting that will allow you to put the files needed to run your site.